# How to create fields in a class using Symbol

Tags: javascript

I have class Movie. Movie constructor should provide a generation of unique product id within the application no matter how many products are created. You also need to define a field with the name of the movie. But according to the condition, for this I have to use Symbol data type. How can i do this?

```js
class Movie {
  constructor(name) {
    //here I need to generate a unique id; 
    //here I need to define name fields
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this really Javascript or Java?

Comment: It is Javascript

Comment: are you referring to this [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand a bit how to use it with classes

Comment: What is the desired result? How do you expect to use the symbol? Should the “product” (or “movies”?) be stored somewhere? How will the `Movie` class be used? Please [edit] and clarify. You can try to explain it using pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Movie {
  sym = Symbol('symbol description')

  constructor(name) {
    this.symInConstructor = Symbol('symbol description')
    // this.sym != this.symInConstructor
    // M1.sym == M2.sym  <=>  M1 == M2
  }
}
// remeber, Symbol() != Symbol(), each call creates a unique one
```

However note that you can't ever serialize a Symbol.
If you need a serializable thingy, generate uuid or whatever

Also it may have sense to not use Symbol, but to use the class instance itself, I don't see how the Symbol may be used

Comment: wait, seems like I didn't understand the question properly

Answer (score -1):

Create a global constant, and use square brackets access

```
const MovieName = Symbol('a key for MovieName') 

class Movie {

    [MovieName] = "The Movie";

    ["myString"] = "is equivalent to:"
    // myString = "is equivalent to:"
    // and must be used for Symbols as

    constructor() {
        this[MovieName] = "The Movie in constructor"
    }

    // may keep is somewhere like this for usage in other places
    static movieNameSymbol = MovieName
}
```

Comment: This might just be a guess, not an answer. The question says something about a _“unique product id within the application no matter how many products are created”_ and that the _“Movie constructor should provide a generation”_ of that somehow. The constructor isn’t generating anything and if `MovieName` is supposed to be the unique ID, then this code only ever generates one of them.